# Applications and meaning of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I learned the mean value theorem in basic calculus as:
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{ (b - a)}$$
In some questions, we have used this theorem e.g. to calculate the maximum and minimum possible values for $f(b)$ given the interval $[a, b]$ like this:

$$f(b) = f'(c)  (b - a) + f(a)$$

But I don't fully understand how we can use the MVT like this - isn't the function fluctuating in between $[a, b]$?

And if so, how can we just use the derivative of some point in the interval $[a, b]$ as our "average" so to speak, to calculate $f(b)$?

Any comments would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Tke a look at the classical drawing (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcI/MeanValueTheorem_files/image001.gif)

Comment: Do you know the formulation of the mean value theorem? I don't really see what it is you don't understand. It says there's a $c$ such that the first equation is true, then there's obviously a (the same) $c$ that make your second equation true.

Comment: The point $c$ which makes this true is _very specific_, you can't choose just any point $c \in [a, b]$. The theorem is that there exists such a $c$.

Comment: @Joppy: You should turn this into a full answer, I think you've accurately pinpointed the the problem here.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I understand the idea of the theorem. But I didn't understand how it was used in a linear approximation to the original function. Now I get it. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your title suggests that you are interested in applications of the MVT.  In my work (I am an economist) I use (generalizations of) the MVT to "eliminate averages".  More specifically, let $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  The average value of $g$ on $[a,b]$ is given by 
$$
\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(x) dx.
$$
The MVT lets me replace this average with $g(c)$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. This type of result holds much more generally, for example with $g$ defined on a connected borel set of finite measure.

Comment: That really helps Not_Dustin. I was looking for that, an application of MVT in a real world example.